# 3.4 urllib.request.urlretrieve time between block reads increases after a few MB

Tags: python, download, urllib

I'm using a little script to automatically download multiple large files. To achieve that I tried the urllib.request.urlretrieve function and my only problem is, that after downloading about 5MB the time between each block read increases massively and my download speed is quartered because of that.

During the first 5MB of download, each block read happens very fast and my reporthook reports fluidly on the amount of data downloaded. But after that, each block read takes about half a second.

Does anyone know what causes this?

Edit:
The relevant code is this:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, fileName, reporthook=downloadProgress)
```

There really isn't more behind it. Whether I use the reporthook or not doesn't change anything as well. I tried it on multiple sites now and it still happens every time. I'll try it via

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
```

now to disguise myself as a Firefox client, maybe that'll work.

Edit2: Nope that didn't work either.

Comment: Weird. I assume your hard drive has plenty of space for the downloads. Maybe the server just doesn't like bots and is throttling your script's downloads. Have you tested the script on other sites to see if the slowdown always happens? Perhaps you should post some code so we can verify that your script's not doing something odd.

Comment: @PM2Ring Alright, I added the information in my OP. I'll contact my sysadmin, I suspect that my apartment has some weird artificial download-slowing since when we started using a captive portal.

Comment: Oh. That captive portal could certainly be the culprit. But I can't offer any advice, since I know almost nothing about them. Maybe your sysadmin will have a suggestion. Good luck!